# Looping through a list and matching several conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

Im trying to create a method that grades a quiz. It works fine if the quiz-question only has one correct answer, but I'm having a hard time handleing multiple correct answers.

I first do a check to see how many correct answers the current question has. If its more than 1 than I need a method that checks if the users answer is a perfect match to the correct answers.

So, if there is a question with 2 correct answers, and the user only checked in 1 of them, he does not get a score.

Any ideas on a method of checking that the number of answers that are correct answers match the correct answers?

I think LINQ would be a good fit here but I'm a total noob on it. Maybe adding all correct answers to a new list and matching with .Contains would be a solution?

The classes look like:

```
List<Question>

Question-Class
- List<Answers>
    -(string) AnswerText
    -(bool) CorrectAnswer

- List<string> UserAnswerToQuestionText
```

Pseudo Code:

```
if (currentquestion has more than one correct answer)
if (UserAnswerText == correctAnswerX && UserAnswerText == correctAnswerY) 

nrofCorrectAnswers++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code for a better answer?

I think it could be something like this:

```
int correctAnswersCount = yourlist.Count(answer => answer.Contais(UserAnswerText));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do this with linq

So this down to how you model your questions and answers.

Make a class for your question and then make a class for your answer something like this, your question class could contain a list of answers:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId {get; set;}
    public string QuestionText {get; set;}
    public List<Answer> Answers {get; set;
}

public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId {get; set;}
    public int QuestionId {get; set;}
    public string AnswerText {get;set;}
}
```

So you have a relationship between question and answer. Then to check your answers against the answer given do this:

```
var userAnswers = new List(Answer);
//populate your useranswers here

foreach(var question in Questions)
{
    var answersForQuestion = question.Answers.Select(a=>a.QuestionId == question.Id);
    if (userAnswers.FindAll(ua => ua.QuestionId == questionId).Length == question.Answers.Count())
    {
        //correct amount of answers. check for actual answers
        if (userAnswers.Any(ua => question.Answers.Contains(a=>a.Id == ua.Id))
    //correct answers made
    {
}
```

This assumes fixed answers for questions (ie multiple choice) if they have typed in the answer it might be more tricky

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is definitely a step forward! :-)

Altough my class looks like this, so the users answers is in a list of strings, can you still iterate them like that with linq?

Comment: Yes you can just change Id for the text. You'll need to do some formatting and validation since strings change.